# 403 tomcat after login

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a tomcat error, already I searched the net and found nothing to clarify the error reason. Come on ..

I installed Tomcat 5.5.36 on a server with java 1.7 64-bit, and set the `server.xml` to authenticate to a table of SQL server.

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm"     connectionURL="jdbc:sqlserver://banco:1433;databaseName=database;user=usuario;password=123456;SelectMethod=Direct" 
    debug="99" driverName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" 
    roleNameCol="ID_ROLE" userCredCol="SENHA" userNameCol="LOGIN" userRoleTable="TABELA" userTable="TABELA"/>
```

The problem that the system goes up and when I type the correct user and password it shows a screen with the message:

> HTTP Status 403: Access to the requested resource Has Been Denied

If I type a user and password Invalid it validates correctly, the error only occurs after login.

I did the same setup on my notebook and the same configuration, and works here. Has anyone seen this error?

Comment: Can you get the login screen? In most cases the login should not show to you but error page.

Comment: I can't, because it is ocurring only in the server of client. The strange is that error show after the correct login.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: why Tomcat 5 ?

Comment: It is a requisite of client. But i tested in my computer with the same configuration and worked.

Comment: @user3670718 thank you for that piece of information. I can only hope they know which security issues they might run into ...

Answer (score 0):

You can try it by changing the `auth-method` in the `CATALINA_BASE\webapps\manager\WEB-INF\web.xml` to point the `auth-method` set to `FORM`. The `realm-name` does not matter.

```xml
<login-config>   
  <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>   
  <realm-name>Tomcat Manager Application</realm-name> 
</login-config>
```

If you want to keep only one `Realm` in the `server.xml`, comment out the default one.